# Ascii String Converter in C

Tags: c, string, ascii

I'm a beginner in doing this sort of problem.
Below is a question and also the code I was trying to develop based on the given question.  I see that whenever I add the input string, it doesn't proceed further.
The question is:

Super ASCII String Checker:
**In the Byteland country a string "S" is said to super ascii string if and only if count of each character in the string is equal to its ascii value.
In the Byteland country ascii code of 'a' is 1, 'b' is 2 ...'z' is 26. 
Your task is to find out whether the given string is a super ascii string or not.
Input Format: 
First line contains number of test cases T, followed by T lines, each containing a string "S".
Output Format: 
For each test case print "Yes" if the String "S" is super ascii, else print "No" 
Constraints:
1<=T<=100
1<=|S|<=400, S will contains only lower case alphabets ('a'-'z').**

Here's what i did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void main()
{
    char s[40];
    int i,j,count=1;
    bool p;
    printf("\nEnter the string:");
    scanf("%s",s);
    int n = strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(s[i]==s[j+1])
                count++;
               }
            int asc = toascii(s[i])-96;
            if(asc == count){
                p = true;
                count=0;
            }
            else
                p=false;
    }
    if(p)
        printf("Yes, the given string is super string");
    else
        printf("No, it ain't a super string");
}
```

Comment: note: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: note 2: `scanf("%s",s);` --> `scanf("%39s",s);`

Comment: note 3: `if (p == true)` --> `if (p)`

Comment: Your buffer is also insufficient. `s[40]` is not big enough to hold the input string when it is 400 characters long.

Comment: And your `p` may be not initialized before testing it in `if (p == true)`

Comment: Also, you need to include `<ctype.h>` to use `toascii()` function.

Comment: And you are not using your `c` variable.

Comment: Basically, you need to check your compiler warnings, not only errors. Compile your code with `gcc -Wall -O2 main.c` and fix all the warnings. Furthermore, you can use `cppcheck` and `sparse` static analyzers to figure out remaining problems. Just saying :)

Comment: And algorythm is wrong : a => No, it ain't a super string ... because 95 should be 96 = 0x60 because ascii code of 'a' is 97 = 0x61. But if you fix it, it says bzb is correct because it only keeps the last character. You should step your code through a debugger to see what happens

Comment: And the Judge will also fail your answer due to the verbose output not matching the question's requirement. But you had probably better add `newline`.

Comment: You only reset `count` when `count == asc`. There's also an error in`your basic logic: `p = true` and p = false` shouldn't be in if/else stalements, because that means that you only consider the result of the last test.l Start with `p = true` and set `p = false` when one of the letter counts doesn't match. Once that happens, the overall result must be `false` and there's no way to get it back to `true` again.

Comment: ...and, the Judge won't be expecting to get `"\nEnter the string:"` in the output - will be seen as part of an incorrect answer.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta , that worked for me.Its actually working for input string like 'abb','acbbcc'.But as you can see in the for loop, i compared the s[i] value with s[j+1] ,but for input string like 'eaeebbee',it's actually not printing the "Yes, the given string is a super string".Instead its printing "No, it ain't a super string".I know its because of that comparison loop,i dont get the logic.

Comment: When j == n - 1, then s[j + 1] will reach the null byte. Not problematic, but unnecessary.

Comment: I don't see a counter where the input specifies how many strings you're going to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler to split your code with a function that would test is a string is a super string, because as soon as for one letter the count is not equal to is value you know that you can immediately return false. With your logic it means that you should have :

```
        else {
            p=false;
            break;
        }
```

And replace the silly `count=1` initialization with `count=0` !

Here is a fixed version (could not test it, my compiler have no stdbool.h)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isSuperString(const char *s)
{
    int i,j;
    int n = strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        int count=0;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(s[i]==s[j])
                count++;
            }
            int asc = s[i]-96;
            if(asc != count){
                return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char s[401];
    printf("\nEnter the string:");
    scanf("%400s",s);
    if(isSuperString(s))
        printf("Yes, the given string is super string");
    else
        printf("No, it ain't a super string");
    return 0;
}
```

But the main that was asked you is :

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, cr;
    char s[401];                    // max 400 characters in input
    cr = scanf("%d", &n);           // always control input
    if (cr != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error at first line\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cr = scanf("%400s",s);      // always limit input strings
        if (cr != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error at test line %d\n", i+1);
            return 1;
        }
        if(isSuperString(s))
            printf("Yes %s\n", s);
        else
            printf("NO  %s\n", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your code isn't anywhere near the required logic, I'll give you some pointers.

You need to count the number of letters of each type. That means that you need 26 counters, one for each type of letter. I recommend using an array, for example `int counters[26];`

For each string "S" to test you need to first set all counters to 0.

Then loop over the string, and for each letter increase the counter for that letter.

Last, loop over the counters and check if they are equal to their value. Note that 0 is also acceptable (the letter doesn't appear in the string at all).
If any letter fails the test, print "No\n" else print "Yes\n".

Continue with the next string.

Comment: Its the first time I like this aproach of an answer on SO. +1